# Is there a way to create an Input dialog in pyqt5 that does not close after clicking ok button

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qinputdialog

Is there any way I can create an Input Dialog with a comboBox that does not close after clicking the ok button.
I tried using

> QInputDialog.setOption(QInputDialog[NoButtons, on=True])

That didn't work. I tried using a second window but couldn't configure it correctly.

Also, is there any way I can use that OK button signal for my logic elsewhere?

Comment: explain yourself better since your question is not clear, it also shows what you have tried even if it does not work.

Comment: Sorry I'll edit it right away..

Comment: provide a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to open a QInputDialog with the option `QInputDialog.NoButtons`, you can do this:

```
dg = QInputDialog()
dg.setOption(QInputDialog.NoButtons)
dg.setComboBoxItems(['Item A', 'Item B', 'Item C'])
dg.exec_()
```

The purpose of the QInputDialog class is to provide a very simple and convenient way to get user input, without much room for customization. The OK button signal always connects to the dialog's `accept` slot. If you want to change the settings for various signals and slots, I would suggest subclassing QDialog and building your own. Here is a simple example where the window will not close when OK is pressed, instead the current item is just printed to the shell.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class CustomDialog(QDialog):

    item_selected = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, items, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.box = QComboBox()
        self.box.addItems(items)
        btn = QPushButton('Ok')
        btn.clicked.connect(self.ok_pressed)
        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.box)
        vbox.addWidget(btn)

    def ok_pressed(self):
        self.item_selected.emit(self.box.currentText())


class Template(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        dg = CustomDialog(['Item A', 'Item B', 'Item C'], self)
        dg.item_selected[str].connect(self.do_something)
        dg.exec_()

    def do_something(self, item):
        print(item)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = Template()
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Great!
Thank you!